# User authentication design, are users people?

Tags: authentication

The application is written in Ruby on Rails but the problem I am facing is more a design matter than language related.

the system provides service to a number of users to maintain a registry. So it relates persons to things. As such it has a model called Person representing owners and it has a model called User representing those who manage the registry.

Now a new requirement has arisen to allow People to log in and be able to change personal details which it was not required for the original design.

The question is how to refactor the application to allow this new requirement in?

One easy solution is to create Users for each person who request login credentials and link user to person entity but that is not very DRY as some fields such as firstname, surname etc. are in both classes and in particular, that is precisely the data people will be able to change. Besides User and Person are stored in separate tables.

The other possibility I was considering is to make one to extend the other but having data in separated tables it makes it a bit messy. Additionally the logical extension would be User <- Person as an user is (generally) a person but thinking on the implementation Person <- User is quite a lot easier.

One last option could be to scrap User and move login credentials into Person leaving logon fields empty for those who won't log in and half of the fields empty for those just login in.

Can you think of a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could think about how this should ideally work if you were to write the application bottom-up, and then figure out how to make a reasonable compromise between that and your current setup. Here are some generic inputs.

As authentication is involved, you need an "Identity" that can be authenticated. This can be e.g. an email address and an associated password, with email verification.

An Identity can potentially be associated to multiple "Roles" and someone authenticated with the identity can choose which role to perform, e.g. "I am now an administrator" vs. "I am now a regular site user", and the role defines the user's current rights for the logged in identity. Or if you don't need that level of complexity, you can say that an Identity is a (single) Role.

You need some tracking between possible "Rights" and the Role the user is performing. E.g. the simplest setup could be the Identity or Role has some boolean can_edit_profile or can_modify_registry properties.

Whenever a user attempts to perform an action which requires certain Rights, it is simply a matter of looking up the corresponding rights set for the Role being performed by the user, to check whether the user is allowed to proceed.

For your application this may just involve adding a 'can_change_registry' property for your user objects, and check whether that property is True for any code accessing that part of the site.